# Teradata SQL - Date format/transformation timestamp

Tags: date, date-format

I have this table:

lastupdatedate

26-JUN-23 02.47.02,000000 PM

27-JUN-23 10.46.07,000000 AM

27-JUN-23 01.47.03,000000 AM

26-JUN-23 03.02.32,000000 PM

27-JUN-23 10.01.07,000000 AM

26-JUN-23 01.16.08,000000 PM

27-JUN-23 08.12.07,000000 AM

I need this format:

lastupdatedate

26-06-2023 14.47.02,000000

27-06-2023 10.46.07,000000

27-06-2023 01.47.03,000000

26-06-2023 15.02.32,000000

27-06-2023 10.01.07,000000

26-06-2023 13.16.08,000000

27-06-2023 08.12.07,000000

I'm trying to extract the date using substring but i get this:

select cast(substring(lastupdatedate,1,9) as date format 'dd-mmm-yy')

lastupdatedate

26/06/1923

27/06/1923

27/06/1923

26/06/1923

27/06/1923

26/06/1923

27/06/1923